# Python: What is the best practice to execute 50 python functions?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I work for a site where I am executing around 50 python functions one by one in a .py file. I just want to know whether is this the best practice or is there a better more robust way ?.

```
def func1()
    Does some processing

def func50()
    Does some processing

if __name__ == "__main__":
    func1()
    func50()
```

Comment: That sounds like you haven't chosen an effective way to organize your code into functions.

Comment: Use a list, perhaps.. (functions in Python are 'just values'). It could also be done with "dynamic variable name access" methods. Really depends on where `func1..func50` come from and/or what the intent is. Such 1..50 names seem suspect.

Comment: There is nothing unreasonable here. Assuming the functions themselves are logical, you've got 50 named functions and they need to be collected in the proper execution order somewhere. Might as well just call them.

Comment: @user2864740 - I don't see how typing 50 function names into a list is better than just calling each of them.

Comment: @tdelaney Seems like that's been covered: "Really depends on where func1..func50 come from and/or what the intent is."

Comment: Why would you just be executing the 50 functions in order? Maybe all the code should just be in a single function?

Comment: @Barmar - Maybe. I worked on a team where we called this "hallway programming". Each function had a task that could be tested separately. Functions were named in a self-descriptive way. A top level function called them all with little to no intermediate processing - like walking down the hall with a mail cart.

Comment: Every function has a critical task for the site and should be executed in order. The thing is the site is now growing bigger with and adds new functionality to those products which ends up in adding additional function.

Comment: @Barmar - In a single function is not possible because the code looks cleaner and secondly every function has a different task,

Comment: Decomposing large functions into smaller ones is a generally recognized software engineering technique. _Short, side effect free, performing a single function only_. If OP had posted compaining about a large untestable function, we'd be suggesting he split it up.

Comment: @tdelaney - So as per you what I am doing is actually right and I should not be worried if the functions count increases ?

Comment: @fear_matrix - Yes... mostly. Like any software design technique, not everyone will agree. But just google "functional programming" for advocates. But this sound like a clean solution in your case. If some of these functions are independent of the others you may even be able to leverage multithreads  / multiprocessing to speed it along.

Answer (score 2):

This a just modular programming where each function is a focused on a single or small set of concerns. It is reasonable to continue with it.

Answer (score 1):

A way of doing this might be to add them to a class, find all functions in that class with a certain prefix and run them. I don't think this is best practice or good design, but it helped me for some testing I had to do in a recent project. The code below assumes that the functions do not have any dependencies.

```py
class MyClassWithManyFunctions:

    def func1(self):
        print("I am func1")

    def func50(self):
        print("I am func2")

    def get_funky(self):
        return [func for func in dir(self) if callable(getattr(self, func)) and func.startswith("func")]

    def run_all(self):
        for method in self.get_funky():
            print(f"Method: {method}")
            getattr(self, method)()

abc = MyClassWithManyFunctions()
abc.run_all()
# Method: func1
# I am func1
# Method: func50
# I am func2
```

Comment: Since class definitions and modules are both *blocks* (see the [Python execution model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html)), there is little to be gained from wrapping a bunch of functions in a class.

Comment: Using this (dirty) code it was convenient to wrap them so I could use `callable(getattr(self, func))`. I am sure this is not optimal, but could help the OP.

Comment: I don't see any reason to do this. For one thing, now all of these functions need to be in a single .py file. For another, they've been coupled in a way they weren't before. This could reduce testability or composition of other solutions using only a subset of the functions.

Comment: Fully agree. I just had to write a quick script where I could dynamically retrieve the functions and execute them.